# Can I connect or merge my Facebook app with my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have created a Facebook app to connect with my website, that allows users to sign up with Facebook.

Beside that, I have also created a Facebook page.

Can I merge or connect the app to the existing Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your app to your page so it appears as one of the app "boxes". Your app would need to be configured to so it can be added to pages.

But if you want to merge your app with your page, you need to contact Facebook to do that. A while ago they merged apps and pages into one and had a process for doing that. As I recall, there was a button but that is no longer available. Facebook will merge all the Likes, Fans, etc. I had to do this with the someecards app/page.